# How to use a current object between two functions C#?

Tags: c#

My code below :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=myDir");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I want to use `driver` in `button1_Click`

Comment: while this question has been answered,  I suggest you to learn the basics of C#.

Comment: Sorry you , English is bad . I can't find this problem . I am trying to learn English and c# basics .
Once again sorry .

Answer (score 2):

This isn´t possible, as it is scoped into your method. Thus it is garbale-collected when the variable gets out of this scope, in your case when you leave that method. You need an instance-variable declared as follows:

```
public class Form1
{
    private readonly IWebdriver _driver;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        this._driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=...");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do someting with your driver
        this._driver...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but you win

Comment: +1 .. removed my comment but I would also suggest to use DI (constructor injection) instead of creating the instance in house

Comment: @Rahul I guess this would overcomplicate the question. OP oviously is missing the basics on OOP, no need to introduce a further level of abstraction.

Comment: @VanCuong, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button to show your appreciation.

Comment: @Rahul thanks you . my english is bad . I will pay more attention when asked .